# ASP.NET Ajax history point retained even after a Response.Redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

We use ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).AddHistoryPoint("d", "value") quite a lot in our site.

Recently we have a page that keep a state in an history point called d.  We do a Response.Redirect to a completely new page without any history point in the URL, but the history point is appended to the URL anyway.

We can't figure out why.  This guy seems to have the same problem only in Firefox, we have it in all browsers for our page: http://forums.asp.net/t/1633135.aspx

Thanks for your help!